# Unable to install Keras and Tensorflow in R

Tags: tensorflow, keras, rstudio, 64-bit

I have been trying to install both tensorflow and keras in Rstudio with no succes, always having the same error.

Many thanks in advance.

This is my code:

devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")

library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
install_keras()

Error in tensorflow::install_tensorflow(method = match.arg(method), conda = conda,  :
Unable to install TensorFlow on this platform.Binary installation is only available for 64-bit platforms.

I am running a 64 bit platform, I dont understand how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider some formatting, thanks

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 x64 bit

Comment: @iguanaoverlord, Please can you try as suggested [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tensorflow/tensorflow.pdf). Thanks!